# Why do many lisps have function names like "foo", "foo-1", "foo-2", etc.?

Tags: function, lisp, naming-conventions, elisp

I've noticed quite a few examples in various Lisps (at least Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp) where two or more functions had identical names except for a trailing number. For example, Emacs Lisp has `eval-last-sexp` and `eval-last-sexp-1`. It also has `print` and `prin1`. This seems to be a general practice, yet one of the first things one learns about programming is to give functions unique and descriptive names. Where does this practice come from?

Comment: Hmm. I guess that was long enough ago that the extra bytes required for more descriptive function names may have actually mattered?

Comment: Certainly. Plus, the thinking was more "wild west" than today.

Comment: The convention is to add a number suffix for a helper function. This was before there were namespaces and such; a function name like foo-1 would suggest "foo is my main function and I exist because the implementation required two functions". A prototypical case is a recursive function where foo is the entry point, but the real work is done by foo-1, recursively.

Comment: ... I guess maybe this was the origin of `prin1` too, and then it proved to be useful in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times this 1 has a semantic meaning (usually, "single"):

- there's `macroexpand` that tries to expands all macros in a form, and `macroexpand-1` that expands only the top-level macro
- there's a common (not standardized) utility `last1`, that returns the last element of a list (as `last` returns the last cons cell)
- the case for `prin1` is more complicated, but as well isn't just a random addition of 1: there's `print`, `princ` and `prin1` (and also `pprint`). See [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) for more details.